# Spree hook usage limited to only 1 special quote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

for example

```
       insert_after :homepage_products do
       "
            <h1>Promotional Item</h1>
            <% products=Product.find_by_sql('select * from products where id in (select product_id from products_taxons where taxon_id in (select id from taxons where name='Promotion'))') %>
            <%= render 'shared/products', :products => products, :taxon => @taxon %>
    "
       end
```

will give this error

```
compile error
inline template:3: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...m taxons where name='Promotion'))') 
                              ^
inline template:3: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
...ons where name='Promotion'))') 
                              ^
```

the problem here is this line

```
select * from products where id in (select product_id from products_taxons where taxon_id in (select id from taxons where name='Promotion')
```

the usage of `'` giving the syntax error
but if i change it to `"Promotion"`, it will look something like this

```
       insert_after :homepage_products do
       "
            <h1>Promotional Item</h1>
            <% products=Product.find_by_sql('select * from products where id in (select product_id from products_taxons where taxon_id in (select id from taxons where name="Promotion"))') %>
            <%= render 'shared/products', :products => products, :taxon => @taxon %>
    "
       end
```

notice how the Promotion words become different colour?
because its overlap with the previous `"`

is there any other "special character" that can be used here?

or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach that I use in my projects is to use alternate Ruby syntax for quoting, such as:

```
insert_after :homepage_products do
  %(
    <h1>Promotional Item</h1>
    <% products=Product.find_by_sql('select * from products where id in (select product_id from products_taxons where taxon_id in (select id from taxons where name="Promotion"))') %>
    <%= render 'shared/products', :products => products, :taxon => @taxon %>
  )
end
```

Of course you can also put your code into a partial and supply the partial to the hook

```
insert_after :homepage_products, 'shared/hooks/_after_homepage_products'
```

It's also worth mentioning that in the latest spree versions this hook system is being deprecated in favor of the [deface](https://github.com/railsdog/deface) gem.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
    <% sql_string = "select * from products where id in (select product_id from products_taxons where taxon_id in (select id from taxons where name=\"Promotion\"))" %>
    <% products=Product.find_by_sql(sql_string) %>
```

just put the \